# Transparent Internationalization API with Python EVE

Tags: eve

We need an i18n API that supports a lot of languages in its queries. What is the best way of use the "Accept-Languages" header key? I'm thinking on having a collection for each language and do a transparent query on the correspondant collection. Or do you think it's better to hardcode the language in the uri?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this flask snippet: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/128/
Anyway using Accept-Language header is not good for this and better to use cookie, but you can make fallback to this header's information if cookie does not exists, to receive header content you can use `flask.request.headers.get('Accept-Language')` but keep in mind that this header might contain not single language, but for example something like this: `da, en-gb;q=0.8, en;q=0.7`

You can use before_request decorator to recognize language before request. Something like this:

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    flask.request.lang = flask.request.cookies.get('lang')
    if lang is None:
        flask.request.lang = flask.request.headers.get('Accept-Language', 'en').split(' ')[0]
```

And than you can use `flask.request.lang` anywhere you need this.

Comment: Thanks, Eugene. Why is it better a cookie? I know how to detect the language, but the problem is that I think we need different collections (one for language so I can use text indexes), so if the client accepts 'en', the action must go to the english collection and if it accepts 'es', it must go to the spanish collection for example.  If not, the client must address the english, the spanish, the french collection explicitly.